# Script options for AWS Adjoin automation through Centrify

Tags: amazon-ec2, scripting, centrify

I am looking for the best scripting option to automate process as below:

Every time an EC2 instance stands up, I'd like to add Centrify package into it, and run Centrify commands to connect to AD server so that EC2 user can be authenticated.

Give this scenario, which scripting language is the best option? I am thinking of Python or bash now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The solution turns out to be a python script which is baked in the AMI, and triggered when an authentication request is initialized.